# Relative paths : going down and up

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I have a bunch of directories, and I have trouble including some files. Here's my structure.

> index.php
>
> vian/vian.php
>
> includes/overall/head_content.php
>
> includes/overall/head.php

Here is my `head_content.php`.

```
testing text
<?php include 'includes/overall/head.php'; ?>
<div class="wrapper row3">
    <div id="container" class="clear"> 
        <div id="content">
```

I want to include that file in `vian/vian.php`

I use `'../includes/overall/head_content.php';`, and the path works since 'testing text' shows up. But it cannot include `includes/overall/head.php`. I vaguely understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

`'../includes/overall/head_content.php';` is used on all my pages, including `index.php`, which is in my root directory.

Comment: Checkout the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). You can then include relative to the current's file directory: `__DIR__ . '/../vian/vian.php'` and similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your structure:

```
 + index.php
 + vian
 |  ` vian.php
 ` includes
    + overall
        + head_content.php
        ` head.php
```

Each file has a specific relationship to the other. Because of that you can make use of relative links from one file to another.

Of help in PHP for that is the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined). It contains the directory in each file automatically. You can use it, to make the relative path an absolute one. Absolute paths are very robust.

Examples:

- From *index.php* to *includes/overall/head.php*:
  `__DIR__ . '/includes/overall/head.php'`
- From *includes/overall/head.php* to *vian/vian.php*:
  `__DIR__ . '/../../vian/vian.php'`
- From *includes/overall/head_content.php* to *includes/overall/head.php*:
  `__DIR__ . '/head.php'`

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Actually, I want to from from vian.php to head.php.

Comment: That would be the second example. You go two steps up and then again down into the *vian* directory.

Comment: Then there is something I'm not getting... I do not want to include vian.php anywhere. I want to include head.php in head_content.php, so it can show up in vian.php

Comment: @Sarah: It all works the same. I added a third example showing that case. Maybe it helps to clarify this for you. Those two files are in the same directory, so it's even pretty straight forward.

Comment: Ah, works. I forgot the `/` before the `../`. Now, should I use this on my whole website from now on? Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, you should use that at each position. So you can train this a little and also you have it the same everywhere. Then you don't need to think so much. Also if you enable error reporting for development PHP will show you the path if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
```